# Translation-oriented CMS/Wiki/HelpPortal systems?

Tags: content-management-system, translation, multilingual, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

We need to run a help portal for users of our application. We want every page to be accesible in several languages.
I want to find a content-management system which would have rich translation features, such as:

- Per-paragraph translation;
- Warnings for translated content that wasn't updated after a change was made to another language;
- Possibility to choose whether to show or hide paragraphs/pages which are not translated;
- Easy and user-friendly switching between languages (e.g. "this page is accessible in the following other languages: ...").

I found a MediaWiki plugin which allows at least some of the above mentioned. Are there any CMSes with native orientation for translations and multilingual content?

Comment: As a MediaWiki contributor I'm biased, but there's really no othe rwiki engine with support for 350+ languages and anything you might want to do with them. Multilingualism and translation features are now also neatly packaged in a single bundle: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MLEB

Answer (score 1):

The [Daisy CMS](http://www.daisycms.org/daisy/index.html) has great built-in translation support.

1. Break your content into sections and translate them individually, or whole pages at a time.
2. You can run a report that tells you which documents have translations that are out of sync with the base language, and which documents don't have translations at all. You can then translate inside the app or export for offline translation and import later.
3. You can exclude untranslated pages and paragraphs from the locale-specific navigation automatically.
4. The menu will automatically show the user which languages are available for a specific page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As the question was asked half a year before, naturally, we already chose a CMS since then. It's Drupal. So far we are quite pleased with it. But I guess, your answer will be useful for other people!

Comment: I'm glad you found something you liked.